# ngbTooltip css not getting applied

Tags: angular, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

I am using ngbTooltip component of @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap library. Although the tooltip appears but it seems css is not getting applied. Library version: "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.1.1"

```
    <input type="password" [ngbTooltip]="passTooltip" placement="end"/>
    
    <ng-template #passTooltip>
    <div>Password Tooltip</div>
    <ng-template>
```